# Regenerating delegation tokens in long running yarn applications

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, apache-twill

I'm using Apache twill to deploy the yarn application. The app is a static hadoop application. As the title says, I couldn't figure out how to regenerate delegation tokens on expiry and ship it to all the containers/application master and make sure they load the same on container restart.

Also, I found the Javadocs on Apache twill a bit lacking. Are there any blogs/mailing lists I can follow for this?

Thanks

Comment: is using `k5start` (https://linux.die.net/man/1/k5start) an option for you?

Comment: @mazaneicha No. The containers need delegation token to load any files(key tabs included) from the dfs

Comment: See last comment here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TWILL-106

Comment: @mazaneicha did I understand this right? Is this happening because my TGT expired before the delegation token does? Preventing the creation of a new one. I don't completely follow what k5start does

Comment: check this out https://github.com/rra/kstart

Comment: @mazaneicha Thanks. I'll check this out. Was my understanding on the cause of the issue correct though?